# I can not update mint

Tags: upgrade

Ok, I figured out that I have an EOL linux version

but when I do

```
do-release-upgrade
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
ImportError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
```

So I check CommandNotFound and here is line 27

```
 from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
```

I don't understand it, so can someone tell me whats wrong?

Here is the full file: http://jpst.it/EL2r

Comment: please, edit your answer with additional informations. If you don't have anything important, installing new version of Mint from scratch sounds like a better idea.

Comment: Ok I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal behavior for a functioning system. Looks like you have some obsolete repo references in there. I'm not familiar with Mint, but you can probably disable the local repo pointing to your CD-ROM unless you're actually using it to speed things up. Also, why are you pointing to *Ubuntu* repos. Are those binaries compatible with Mint?  Nonetheless, if you visit any of those URLs they're actually 404'ing so you should probably comment them out in your repo files and try again. I believe the changes can be made here: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I found out that saucy mint is EOL but trying to update to a newer version, there is no Update-Manage and I cant use SUDO apt-get install

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy in you list) is EOL. You should update [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29)

> Support for Ubuntu 13.10 ended on 17 July 2014.

You can upgrade from terminal as described in [ultimate guide for uprading to new version](https://askubuntu.com/a/110483/429987)

```
do-release-upgrade
```

or follow any other guide you can find on the internet, such as [howtoforge](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-from-linux-mint-13-maya-to14--nadia-with-apt):

> open /etc/apt/sources.list:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> This is how the file looks for Linux Mint 13:
>
> Now replace `maya` with `nadia` and all occurrences of `saucy` with `quantal`
>
> Then update && upgrade
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo reboot
> ```

Comment: Yea I found that out myself, I want to update to a newer release but I cant use sudo apt-get install update-manager

Comment: you can upgrade from command line.

Comment: I wont work at all

Comment: It does this - ImportError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'

Comment: another possibility based on the google

Comment: Linux Mint does not upgrade the way Ubuntu does. I posted a link in my answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official answer: Linux Mint does not support upgrading the way Ubuntu does. You appear to be trying to do an Ubuntu upgrade with Linux Mint and that appears to be the source of the confusion.

What follows is not my view. It is from Linux Mint.

[How to upgrade to a newer release - Linux Mint Community](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2)

From our point of view, Ubuntu does three things wrong:

1. It doesn't make it easy for you to backup your data, nor does it warn you to do so.
2. It automatically asks you to upgrade to the latest version. You click on the "upgrade" button and there's no turning back. No explanation about the risks involved, no explanation about the pros and cons... just a simple button to click for a process you likely don't understand.
3. It uses a "package" upgrade method. See section C2 for pros and cons associated with this method.

The only advantage Ubuntu offers is that it makes the process trivial and fully automated. Though, considering the risks and the way it upgrades your system, this should be considered dangerous. We do not even recommend this on the command line, so to have it triggered from the click of a button is just not acceptable to us. It's easy alright, but it's not the right solution. Sometimes things are important enough for us to take the time to do them properly. When it comes to upgrading, it's important to backup your data, to test the release before installing it and to avoid any broken or conflicting packages. The method chosen by Ubuntu is fully graphical and extremely easy to use, but it fails to do just that, and that's what matters the most.